# Error in groupby with fn_split function SQLAlchemy with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have written a custom function to split the col_name and select 2nd item of it
e.g. 32231 will be selected from '22122-32231-fsdfs-343"
Getting error that there should be same column in group by clause or aggregate function which is there in select clause
What am I missing?

SQLAlchemy Query

```
column_number = Model.custom_split_part(Model.col_name, '-', 2)
file_numbers = session.query(column_number).distinct()\
                        .filter(Model.col_id== col_id)\
                        .group_by(column_number)\
                        .order_by(column_number)\
                        .all()
```

Custom Split Function

```
@staticmethod
    def custom_split_part(row_data, split_on, col):
        cnt = 1
        while (cnt!=col):
            data = func.substring(row_data, 1, func.charindex(split_on, row_data)-1)
            if col == cnt:
                return data
            row_data = func.substring(row_data, func.charindex(split_on, row_data)+1, func.length(row_data))
            cnt+=1
        if cnt != col:
            return ''
        return data
```

I want to select the required number for the col_name and use it in group_by clause

Raw SQL Query fetched from terminal

```
SELECT DISTINCT substring(dbo.[Model].[col_name], 1, charindex('-', dbo.[Model].[col_name]) - 1)
FROM dbo.[Model]
WHERE dbo.[Model].[col_id] = col_id
GROUP BY substring(dbo.[Model].[col_name], 1, charindex('-', dbo.[Model].[col_name]) - 1) 
ORDER BY substring(dbo.[Model].[col_name], 1, charindex('-', dbo.[Model].[col_name]) - 1)
```

Error Message

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) 
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Column 'dbo.Model.col_name' 
is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. 
(8120) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Column 'dbo.Model.col_name' 
is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (8120); 
[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if 
SELECT DISTINCT is specified. (145); 
[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Comment: Odd that you are getting that error when you have an identical expression in your select and your group by.

Comment: Try removing `distinct`

Comment: Tried removing distinct but still not working